# Trouble Installing Package from a Local Apt Repo

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I am having some issues installing a package from a local apt-repo. I followed the guide below to set up the apt repo and it seems to be working fine. When I run the update-debs command and apt-get update it appears to add the additional packages to the Packages.gz file.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal

The problem is that when I attempt to install the package, it tells me that the package is not found. I also cannot seem to see the package if I run `apt-cache search $package_name`

The specific error message that I get is `E: Unable to locate package`

### Additional Information

Output of apt-get update

```
ops@ops-repo:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign file: ./ InRelease
Ign file: ./ Release.gpg
Ign file: ./ Release
Ign http://mirrors.linode.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign file: ./ Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports InRelease
Ign file: ./ Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty Release
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates Release
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports Release
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/main Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.linode.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

I added an `ops.list` directory inside of `/etc/apt/sources.d/` which contains this line:

```
deb file:/usr/local/debs ./
```

I believe that this is what is being referenced at the top of apt-get update when it talks about `Ign file:`.

Comment: There are no `Hit`s or `Get`s at all with your local repo. For some reason it can't reach it. Each `Ign` is an error, some of which can be ignored.

Comment: Hmm, that is good to know. Do I need to do anything special to get sources to load from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list?

Comment: No, the source is being loaded from your list file, something else is wrong. Can you check if there's anything corresponding to your local repo `/var/lib/apt/lists` - might be in a sub directory?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar and found in the end that installing the package would work just fine, even though `apt-cache policy package` said it was not available, and threw the error message you are reporting, however with `N:` instead of `E:`. (However, `apt-cache search package` returns empty output for me, rather than the error message.)

Running `strace` on `apt-cache` reveals that it only opens a subset of the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` -- specifically, it seems to bypass my private repo, maybe because it has a slightly funny file name (`myserver.internal_%7etripleee_repo_Packages`).